# How to read selected radio button value in google form by using Google App script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

Working on a google form . I have two radio button . Based on user selected radio button i should call different function in google App script. I am new to this technology. Can someone help me on this..

I am tryimg with FormApp class. But not able to find a way.

```
function myFunctiontest() {
   var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
   var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var itemr,title,res;
  for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
  var formResponse = formResponses[i];    
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[j]   
    var item =  itemResponse.getItem();//.asMultipleChoiceItem();
                itemResponse.getItem().getType(),    
                itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
                itemResponse.getResponse();
                res = itemResponse.getResponse().;
    if (item.getType() == 'MULTIPLE_CHOICE' && res == 'A')  
    {
       itemr= itemResponse.getItem().asMultipleChoiceItem(),    
       title =itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
       res =  itemResponse.getResponse();
       Logger.log('Response Type : ',itemr );
       Logger.log('Response Type title  :',title );    
       Logger.log('Response Type  res:',res ); 
    }

     }            
  }

}
```

Comment: You cannot directly run  a script when a user selects a button, but only after he submits his form.

Comment: For example. I have two  radio button called A and B and i have one submit button in form.  If i choose radio button A and click submit button means one function should call. If i choose radio button B and click submit button means another should call.

Comment: This is possible. Just please provide some of your own efforts to write such a script before asking for help where you got stuck. Basically: You need to use the onFormSubmit trigger and access the form response items.

Comment: Yes i have tried the attached code.But it is returning all responses instead of current response. Could you please help me on getting current selected value.

Answer (score 0):

### Write two additional functions and call one them depending on the outcome of a conditional statement

- Thereby, if it is only a specific question which answer should induce the running of a function - you specify which question it is by providing its index.

Sample:

```
function myFunctiontest() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var itemr,title,res;
  for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
    var formResponse = formResponses[i];    
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
    var questionNumber = 1;
    var selectedQuestion = itemResponses[questionNumber-1];
    var item = selectedQuestion.getItem();
    var response = selectedQuestion.getResponse();    
    if (item.getType() == 'MULTIPLE_CHOICE' && response == 'A')  
    {
      myFunction1(); 
    }
    else if (item.getType() == 'MULTIPLE_CHOICE' && response == 'A'){
      myFunction2(); 
    }       
  }  
}


function myFunction1(){
  Logger.log("You called function 1");
}

function myFunction2(){
  Logger.log("You called function 2");
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried with the above. But still am getting multiple responses instead of current response.

Comment: Hi ,   I have done the changes and it is working fine when i am trying via running the script from script editor were as navigating from it is not working. Kindly help me to sort out this.

Comment: You should only get the response to `var questionNumber = 1`, not multiple responses. What do you mean by `navigating from `? If you want the script to run automatically, you have to bind it to an [onFormSubmit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers).